# Testing controller not passing parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im currently working on my test cases for ruby on rails and realize that the parameter that i was passing is not being passed to my controller.

this is my test case for my controller

```
  test "should get addUser" do
  user_info = User.create_user("TEST1","TEST1")
  assert_equal(user_info,true,"Assert Failed")
```

The User.create_user contains

```
def self.create_user(username,password)
    if username == "" || password == "" and username == nil || password == nil
        register = User.new({:username => username,:password => password})
    end
    return register.save
end
```

the result also shows 2 assertions but i only declare one assert.

Comment: You should use validations on the User model, rather than creating class actions to validate. Using validations means that the User object gets checked whenever it's saved, which you can simply begin/rescue and have a much simpler action.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your condition :

```
if username && password && !username.empty? && !password.empty?

unless ['', nil].include?(username) || ['', nil].include?(password)
```

Will both work.

Finally, in Rails, you can use `blank?` if multiple spaces is not a valid value as well (which is generally a good idea for usernames and passwords):

```
unless username.blank? || password.blank?
```

--

```
if username == "" || password == "" and username == nil || password == nil
```

Will pass only if (username or password is empty) and (username or password is nil) so only with these combinations :

```
{ password: '', username: nil }
{ password: nil, username: '' }
```

Regarding the 2 assertions, We will need more code to help (Missing end at the end of the test at least here)

Comment: In Rails the `blank?` function will simplify/clean-up that condition testing for nil or empty in one.

Comment: true, but `'    '.blank?` is true as well. editing my answer